# How can we make the general view, because code is reusing in different web pages?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

How can we make the general view of following web pages. From that general view we can implement if conditions to redirect to the view.
here is the files picture:
[Calling all weeks from links in index.cshtml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKJbE.png)
my cshtml files looks like:

week3.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Testing Weeks API";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_GameLayout.cshtml";

}
<script src="/lib/pixi.js/browser/pixi.js" ></script>
<script src="/OtherJS/pixi-viewport.js"></script>
<script src="/OtherJS/pixi-scrollbox.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/week-3.js" type="module"></script>
```

week4.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Testing Weeks API";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_GameLayout.cshtml";

}
<script src="/lib/pixi.js/browser/pixi.js" ></script>
<script src="/OtherJS/pixi-viewport.js"></script>
<script src="/OtherJS/pixi-scrollbox.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/week-4.js" type="module"></script>
```

I just dont want 10 weeks views file, I need just one weeks.cshtml from where I can redirect to links using if condition.
Thanks in Advance for solution

Comment: The difference between week3.cshtml and week4.cshtml is only `<script src="~/js/week-xxx.js" type="module"></script>`.Do you mean you want to pass data to the cshtml,and can decide which js to load?

Comment: yes sir, you recognized correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just pass a value in viewbag and put a condition on it in your controller file. If that condition fulfills than show week3 else show week4.

```
 public IActionResult Week()
    {
        ViewBag.Name = 1;
        return View();
    }
```

then use it in your Weekcshtml file where you are displaying all weeks.

```
@if(ViewBag.Name == 1){ 
    <script src="~/js/week-3.js" type="module"></script>
    }
else{
    <script src="~/js/week-4.js" type="module"></script>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to pass a data to weeks.cshtml Model,here is a demo:

Model:

```
public class Model{
    public int number { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<script src="~/js/week-@(Model.number).js" type="module"></script>
```

Action:

```
public IActionResult TestJs() {

            return View(new Model {number=3});
        }
```

result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your `index.cshtml` has 10 links for 10 `Week{1-10}.cshtml` files but you want 1 `Week.cshmtl` that programmatically shows all 10 files without having 10 real cshmtl files.

You can simply pass a number with each link, for example in your `index.cshtml` file you can have

```
@foreach (var week in Model.Weeks)
    {
        <a  asp-page="./Week" asp-route-weekNumber="@week.Number"> Week-@week.Number </a>
    }
```

then your `Week.cshtml` would be like

```
@page "{weekNumber:int}"
@model Yournamespace.Pages.Home.WeekModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Testing Weeks API";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_GameLayout.cshtml";

}
<script src="/lib/pixi.js/browser/pixi.js"></script>
<script src="/OtherJS/pixi-viewport.js"></script>
<script src="/OtherJS/pixi-scrollbox.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/week-@(Model.WeekNumber).js" type="module"></script>
```

and your `Week.cshtml.cs` would be like

```
public class WeekModel : PageModel
    {

        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public int WeekNumber { get; set; }

        public IActionResult OnGet(int weekNumber)
        {
            // Do something
            return Page();
        }

    }
```